# How to set a temporary Java classpath in Ubuntu

Tags: java, path

I am writing a Java program and I need to set a temporary classpath that includes my package.  The package is on my Ubuntu desktop, which I am importing as /home/gaurav/Desktop.  Do you have
any idea how to set the Java CLASSPATH temporarily?

Comment: i know this is really junkyard question but i don't know the command i tired by seeing many threads on ubuntu froums not working

Comment: That becomes difficult without any punctuation on your keyboard.

Comment: Harry Joy : i dont have idea how this work export CLASSPATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the Java classpath on Ubuntu the same way as you do on any Linux / UNIX platform (or indeed on Windows ... modulo some minor syntactic differences).  There are two ways:

```
$ java -cp <classpath> some.ClassName arg1 arg2 ...
```

or

```
$ export CLASSPATH=<classpath>
$ java some.ClassName arg1 arg2 ...
```

where `<classpath>` is a sequence of pathnames with ':' separators.

For more details refer to the manual entry for the 'java' command; e.g. [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

---

If you don't understand `export CLASSPATH=...` read the Ubuntu manual entry for `bash`, paying attention to what it says about setting variables, environment variables, and the `export` built-in shell command.  (Hint: `$ man bash`.)

This is temporary.  To make it permanent, add the line to the relevant shell init script; see `man bash` for details.

---

> how do i get details for my path which path i have set

The classpath is a list of pathnames of directories and JAR files that you want the JVM to search in order to find the classes it needs to run your application.  You'll need to figure that out yourself ... or (re-)read the documentation of whatever it is you are trying to run.

Comment: `$ export CLASSPATH=<classpath>` 
by this i set password permanently  or temporary 
how do i get details for my path which path i have set

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a java program from the desktop, you have three choices.

The easy choice is to write a small *shell script* and put that on the desktop. The smallest example might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH YOUR_CLASS_NAME "$*"
```

Next comes the use of 'jarjar' or 'shade' to make one big jar containing all your dependencies, and then run that with java -jar. (As a sub-option, if it's really just for you, you can make a jar with a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF containing a class path with absolute pathnames.)

The more complex choice is to learn to use JNLP to build a launchable item.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can control the classpath with either an environment variable or a command-line option to java.